# Python make montaage of images stored in a 4D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a stack of images stored in a 4D array, e.g. [0, 0, :, :] is the image at the location (0, 0). Now I want to make a montage of the images and store them in a 2D array and do something with the images, then I want to transfer the montage back to a 4D array. How can I manage this with numpy? Following is a schematic of what I want to do. It is shown with a 3D array, but I think you can get the idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the operation can be carried out using [`np.block`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html). You would need to convert to a non-array sequence type for the outer dimensions:

```
l = [list(x) for x in arr]
montage = np.block(l)
```

Alternatively, you can just arrange your dimensions the way you like first, then reshape. The key is to remember that later dimensions get raveled together. So if you have an array with `(A, B)` elements, each of which is an `(M, N)` image, the result should be an `(A * M, B * N)` image. You want the original image pixels from each row to stay contiguous, but the rows to be concatenated. So transpose and reshape like this:

```
a, b, m, n = arr.shape
montage = arr.transpose(0, 2, 1, 3).reshape(a * m, b * n)
```

You can reshape back using the inverse operation fairly easily:

```
stack = montage.reshape(a, m, b, n).transpose(0, 2, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is actually the default behavior of [`np.reshape()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). Just calculate how wide/tall the collage image will be, and then call `np.reshape`. `reshape` again will reverse it.

```py
import numpy as np

# placeholder data -- 4 images that are 5x5
image = np.arange(4 * 5 * 5 * 3).reshape(4, 5, 5, 3)

# 2x2 grid of images
collage = image.reshape(10, 10, 3)

result = collage.reshape(4, 5, 5, 3)

assert np.array_equal(image, result)
```

---

**Edit:** I misunderstood the question. I assumed that the 4D array was a 1D-list of NxMx3 RGB images. If, instead, it is a 2D grid of 2D (single channel) images, I can't think of a clever way to do it with numpy operations. But, it shouldn't be to slow to just use a python for-loop.

(assuming row-major order)

```py
# rows = number of rows in image grid
# cols = number of cols in image grid
# width = width of each image
# height = height of each image

rows, cols, height, width = images.shape

collage = np.empty(rows * height, cols * width, dtype=images.dytpe)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        y = i * height
        x = j * range
        collage[y:y+height, x:x+width] = images[i, j]
```

Then to reverse just flip it:

```py
result = np.empty(rows, cols, width, height, dtype=collage.dytpe)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        y = i * height
        x = j * range
        images[i, j, :, :] = collage[y:y+height, x:x+width]
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is argument 3 in the image variable. I guess you are assuming RGB image and 3 in the channel for colors? But what I have is tiff images, meaning there is just one channel for intensity, and the images are already stored in the array of [x, y, 5, 5] (x times y images, each has a shape of 5 by 5). x and y is the location where I want to place it in the montage.

Comment: I edited the answer. Hopefully that helps

Comment: @Simon. All that info should be in the question.